# Jira / Cards assigned to a user in a given timeframe

Tags: jira, jql

We use Jira extensively in our project, and I am attempting to create some custom reports which should list all cards assigned to a user within a given timeframe.

For example: Get all cards I worked on in August 2014.

Is that even possible without direct DB access?

P.S. I have tried playing with the update timestamp, yet it will then also list cards which were assigned to me anytime but not necessarily in the timeframe I am interested in. This will NOT work -->

```
assignee = currentUser() and updated > "2014/08/01" and updated < "2014/10/31"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should be like:

```
assignee was currentUser() DURING ("2014/08/01", "2014/10/31")
```

From looking at the [Advanced Searching documents](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRA/Advanced+Searching).